# For flutter website, connecting Stripe Account (payment gateway)

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I want to connect my Stripe account to the test mode and integrate it with my Flutter website. While there don't seem to be any errors in the code below, it doesn't work perfectly.

In the code provided above, the payment gateway is not being displayed, and an error message is appearing, indicating 'Unsupported operation: Platform_operating System.' Could you please provide guidance on how to address and resolve this issue?

```
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_stripe/flutter_stripe.dart';
    import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class PaymentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PaymentPageState createState() => _PaymentPageState();
}

class _PaymentPageState extends State<PaymentPage> {
  Map<String, dynamic>? paymentIntent;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Stripe.publishableKey = kIsWeb
        ? "pk_test_your_key_for_web" 
        : "pk_test_your_key_for_mobile"; 
  }

  Future<void> _startPayment() async {
    try {
      // Check if the platform is web
      if (kIsWeb) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Web platform is not supported for payments',
        );
        return;
      }

      paymentIntent = await createPaymentIntent('100', 'INR');

      await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          billingDetails: BillingDetails(
            name: 'YOUR NAME',
            email: 'YOUREMAIL@gmail.com',
          ),
          paymentIntentClientSecret: paymentIntent!['client_secret'],
        ),
      );

      // Display Payment sheet
      await displayPaymentSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> displayPaymentSheet() async {
    try {
      // Display the payment sheet.
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();

      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Payment successfully completed');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      if (e is StripeException) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Error from Stripe: ${e.error.localizedMessage}',
        );
      } else {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Unforeseen error: ${e}');
      }
    }
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> createPaymentIntent(
      String amount, String currency) async {
    try {
      Map<String, dynamic> body = {
        'amount': calculateAmount(amount),
        'currency': currency,
      };

      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents'),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: body,
      );
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } catch (err) {
      throw Exception(err.toString());
    }
  }

  String calculateAmount(String amount) {
    final calculatedAmount = (int.parse(amount)) * 100;
    return calculatedAmount.toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stripe Payment Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: _startPayment,
          child: Text('Make Payment'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, and here's what I found.

According to the [package's documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe):

> To use Stripe on web, it is required to add `flutter_stripe_web` in your `pubspec` file

So add the package [`flutter_stripe_web`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe_web/install) and then fully stop and rebuild your app.

Your code should now work:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Stripe.publishableKey =
        (kIsWeb ? "pk_test_your_key_for_web" : "pk_test_your_key_for_mobile");
  }
```